# Content of a grid item change it's size

Tags: html, css

I'm have four grid items that I want to be perfect squares. I've done this using (25vw) but when I put things in the grids below these square grids they expand and change completely because of the grid below them.

```css
* {

    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.wrapper {

    height: 100vh;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25vw - 3.75px);
    grid-template-rows: minmax(0, 1.25fr) calc(25vw - 3.75px) 7fr 3fr 1.5fr;
    grid-gap: 5px;
}
.attendants {
    background: brown;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 3/4;
}
.header-attendants {
}
.list-attendants {
}
/*the rest is irrelevant*/

.navbar {

    background: white;
    grid-column: 1/5;
    grid-row: 1/2;
}
.webcam {

    background: black;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 2/3;
}
.class-background {

    background: purple;
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 2/3;
}
.events {

    background: green;
    grid-column: 3/4;
    grid-row: 2/3;
}
.tools {

    background: pink;
    grid-column: 4/5;
    grid-row: 2/3;

}
.frame {

    background: yellow;
    grid-column: 2/4;
    grid-row: 3/5;
}
.chat {

    background: red;
    grid-column: 4/5;
    grid-row: 3/4;
}
.three-buttons {

    background: darkgreen;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 4/6;
}
.text-box {

    background: darkred;
    grid-column: 2/4;
    grid-row: 5/6;
}
.sharing-status {

    background: blue;
    grid-column: 4/5;
    grid-row: 4/6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Focus</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="navbar">
            testing...
        </div>
        <div class="webcam">
            testing...
        </div>
        <div class="class-background">
            testing...
        </div>
        <div class="events">
            testing...
        </div>
        <div class="tools">
            testing...
        </div>
    <!-- this is what I'm struggling with, from here -->
        <div class="attendants">
            <div class="header-attendants">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris.
            </div>
            <div class="list-attendants">
                <div class="attendant">
                    <p class="name">John</p>
                    <p class="role">teacher</p>
                    <p class="joined-at">0:00</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- to here -->
        <div class="frame">
            testing...
        </div>
        <div class="chat">
            testing...
        </div>
        <div class="three-buttons">
            testing...
        </div>
        <div class="text-box">
            testing...
        </div>
        <div class="sharing-status">
            testing...
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ideally, it would look like this, regardless of the content the grids:

```css
* {

    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}


.wrapper {

    height: 100vh;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25vw - 3.75px);
    grid-template-rows: minmax(0, 1.25fr) calc(25vw - 3.75px) 7fr 3fr 1.5fr;
    grid-gap: 5px;
}


.navbar {

    background: white;
    grid-column: 1/5;
    grid-row: 1/2;
}


.webcam {

    background: black;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 2/3;
}


.class-background {

    background: purple;
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 2/3;
}


.events {

    background: green;
    grid-column: 3/4;
    grid-row: 2/3;
}


.tools {

    background: pink;
    grid-column: 4/5;
    grid-row: 2/3;

}


.attendants {

    background: brown;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 3/4;
    
    
}


.header-attendants {


    

}



.list-attendants {


    

}


.frame {

    background: yellow;
    grid-column: 2/4;
    grid-row: 3/5;
}


.chat {

    background: red;
    grid-column: 4/5;
    grid-row: 3/4;
}


.three-buttons {

    background: darkgreen;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 4/6;
}


.text-box {

    background: darkred;
    grid-column: 2/4;
    grid-row: 5/6;
}


.sharing-status {

    background: blue;
    grid-column: 4/5;
    grid-row: 4/6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Focus</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="navbar">
            testing...
        </div>
        <div class="webcam">
            testing...
        </div>
        <div class="class-background">
            testing...
        </div>
        <div class="events">
            testing...
        </div>
        <div class="tools">
            testing...
        </div>
        <div class="attendants">
            <div class="header-attendants">
                    .
            </div>
            <div class="list-attendants">
                <div class="attendant">
                    <p class="name">John</p>
                    <p class="role">teacher</p>
                    <p class="joined-at">0:00</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="frame">
            testing...
        </div>
        <div class="chat">
            testing...
        </div>
        <div class="three-buttons">
            testing...
        </div>
        <div class="text-box">
            testing...
        </div>
        <div class="sharing-status">
            testing...
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `calc()` inside the repeat:

```
repeat(4, calc(25vw - 3.75px))
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, calc(25vw - 3.75px));
  grid-template-rows: minmax(0, 1.25fr) calc(25vw - 3.75px) 7fr 3fr 1.5fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.attendants {
  background: brown;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 3/4;
}

.header-attendants {}

.list-attendants {}


/*the rest is irrelevant*/

.navbar {
  background: white;
  grid-column: 1/5;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

.webcam {
  background: black;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.class-background {
  background: purple;
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.events {
  background: green;
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.tools {
  background: pink;
  grid-column: 4/5;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.frame {
  background: yellow;
  grid-column: 2/4;
  grid-row: 3/5;
}

.chat {
  background: red;
  grid-column: 4/5;
  grid-row: 3/4;
}

.three-buttons {
  background: darkgreen;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 4/6;
}

.text-box {
  background: darkred;
  grid-column: 2/4;
  grid-row: 5/6;
}

.sharing-status {
  background: blue;
  grid-column: 4/5;
  grid-row: 4/6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Focus</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="navbar">
      testing...
    </div>
    <div class="webcam">
      testing...
    </div>
    <div class="class-background">
      testing...
    </div>
    <div class="events">
      testing...
    </div>
    <div class="tools">
      testing...
    </div>
    <!-- this is what I'm struggling with, from here -->
    <div class="attendants">
      <div class="header-attendants">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris.
      </div>
      <div class="list-attendants">
        <div class="attendant">
          <p class="name">John</p>
          <p class="role">teacher</p>
          <p class="joined-at">0:00</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- to here -->
    <div class="frame">
      testing...
    </div>
    <div class="chat">
      testing...
    </div>
    <div class="three-buttons">
      testing...
    </div>
    <div class="text-box">
      testing...
    </div>
    <div class="sharing-status">
      testing...
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

For Some functions you can omit the `calc()` like `min()`, `max()` or `clamp()` but it's not the case for `repeat()`